# Undefined variable: image laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I have a problem in passing the parameter to the view. I have tested the code is work when I put at the SearchController@index. The problem came out if I using another function. When I try to use SearchController@create or others name it does not work. PS: The model is called image.php.

**Controller**

```
    class SearchController extends BaseController {


public function index() // Display view
{


    return View::make('search.search');


}

public function create()
    {
        $keyword = Input::get('keyword');

        //query image model
        $images = image::where('id', 'LIKE', '%'.$keyword.'%')->get();




       return View::make('search.search')
           ->with('image',$images);

    }
```

Route

```
 Route::get('search','SearchController@index');

        Route::post( 'search', array(
            'as' => 'search.search',
            'uses' => 'SearchController@create'
        ) );
```

View

```
{{Form::open(array('url'=>'/search'))}}
    {{Form::text('keyword', null, array('placeholder'=>'search by keyword'))}}
    {{Form::submit('search')}}
{{Form::close()}}

{{Form::open(array('url'=>'', 'files'=>true))}}

    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="">Categories</label>
        <select class="form-control input-sm" name="">
        <option value=""></option>
        </select>
    </div>
    {{Form::close()}}

    @foreach($image as $images)
                 {{$images->image_name}}

             @endforeach


@stop
```

Answer (score 0):

The question hasn't any error message which is the key to your solution.
You didn't specify what error you get?
Does your $Image return something If it returns null It would display Undefined variable $image.
Are you getting the undefined variable  error or something else??

```
//Try dd collection in view
dd($image);
//See what you get...?
```